# What to add or correct to make Tomcat communicate with postgresql database in docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, tomcat, networking, docker-compose

I have built a tomcat app as my api with postgresql as the database. On normal deployment the app works fine where the ttomcat app accesses the db well, bbut not when i test it through the docker, I get the following errors:

```
SEVERE [main] java.sql.SQLException.UserAccounts Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
```

The follwing is my docker compose file;

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  # Postgresql
  postgres_db:
    build: ./database  # dockerfile with env and default sql copy
    container_name: my_database 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
 
  # adminer
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2010:8080
    labels:
      - "adminer.app.com=Database manager"

  # tomcat
  tomcat:
    build: ./api
    container_name: app_api
    labels:
      - "api.app.com=Application backend API"
    environment:
      - CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - "postgres_db"
    ports:
      - "2020:8080"
    links:
      - "postgres_db"
```

Any suggestions, on how to correct this localhost:5432 connection refusal issue. Please I am quite a newbie to docker.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure networking here so that your adminer can connect to database in your case you can make changes and Connect to the same network as postgres_db

version: "3.8"

services:
postgres_db:
build: ./database  # dockerfile with env and default sql copy
container_name: my_database
restart: always
ports:
- '5432:5432'
volumes:
- postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

adminer:
image: adminer
restart: always
ports:
- 2010:8080
labels:
- "adminer.app.com=Database manager"
**network_mode: "service:postgres_db"  # Connect to the same network as postgres_db**

tomcat:
build: ./api
container_name: app_api
labels:
- "api.app.com=Application backend API"
environment:
- CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
restart: always
depends_on:
- postgres_db
ports:
- "2020:8080"
links:
- "postgres_db"

Comment: I got an error when I tried to as you suggested. More so I can access the database through the adminer alright with my already created composer. My problem is the tomcat app. The tomcat container is what is giving me the Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to localhost:5432 refused....